# How I can pass .csv file in UriComponentsBuilder as queryparam

Tags: java, file-upload, webclient

I'm using WebClient for testing my controller test case of the spring boot 2 application.
I want to pass .csv file in query param of UriComponentsBuilder.

Here is my test code :

```
@Test
void testUploadDocument() {
    File file = new File("test/resources/db/restore/sql/system_code_master_list.csv");
    UriComponentsBuilder uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(URL)
            .queryParam("file",new FileSystemResource(file))
            .queryParam("codeType","ICD_10");
    client.post().uri(
            uri.path("/uploadcsv").build().toUriString())
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.ALL)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .isEmpty();
}
```

And Here it my controller method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadcsv", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void uploadDocument (
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile fileParts,
        @RequestParam(name = "codeType", required = true) String codeType)throws IOException {}
```

How can I pass the file in query param?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
void testUploadDocument() {
    
    Resource file = new ClassPathResource("test/resources/db/restore/sql/system_code_master_list.csv");
    MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    builder.part("file", file);

    UriComponentsBuilder uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(URL)
            .queryParam("codeType", "SNOMED_CT");
    client.post().uri(
            uri.path("/uploadcsv").build().toUriString())
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .isEmpty();
   
}
```